# Как переместить главное окно на задний план? tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как переместить главное окно на задний план? tkinter, python

Comment: Вы сами свой вопрос поняли? Убрать с него фокус?

Comment: да, чтобы остальные окна были поверх этого

Comment: Какие остальные и поверх какого?? Я не вижу окон и невижу что-бы сделали скрипт который хотя бы просто окно любое создаёт.

Comment: Основного......

Comment: Вы не прикладывая усилий хотите ликбез по програмированию на питон с использованием tkinter под Windows?

Comment: Нет я только хочу узнать ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```

Также вместо `tk` вы можете подставлять названия переменых которые хранят другие окна. Пример:

```
win = Toplevel(tk)
win.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```